# How to restore mysql database in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have been using XAMPP on Ubuntu for a while and I had created a DB via phpMyAdmin with a single DB and multiple rows.

After having to restart my PC, I could not restart XAMPP, so I did install it again (ran the installed.sh without installing first)

Installation was successful and web server is working fine with old files retained.

But, I find that I cannot access the table any more, even though I see it listed via phpMyAdmin and gives an error "Table does not exists in the engine".

However, I can see the table.ipd, table.frm and db.opt inside /opt/lampp/var/mysql/

Is there a way to restore the table from the XAMPP stack?

Comment: Do you have backup from the database ?\

Comment: no, I only have these *.ipd and *.frm file. The table is innoDB, can I not restore from these files ?

Comment: have you tried to upload it to phpMyAdmin with import and tacking care  of the import format

Comment: u suggest to zip the folder and import ? would it work ?